# Different values predicted by OLS model and Time Series model

Tags: time-series, least-squares, arima

Let us say , I have an explanatory variable X and a dependent variable Y and I use OLS and find Y = 0.5 + 3X.

Now let us assume that both X and Y are time series data, so using ARIMA modelling process, I find that Y(t) = Y(t-1)*0.8 + 1.2.

Let us say that at a future time t = 5, the value of X = 100.
Now, the above 2 formulas will give two different values of Y(t=5). How do you reconcile these two values?

The part in parentheses represents subscript notation.

Comment: The time-series model that you specify is purely autoregressive (it's AR(1)) and does not contain the explanatory variable (X). Is this the specification you have in mind or do you mean to compare a simple linear regression model to a time-series model containing a regression component (i.e. an X variable that is not an autoregressive term)? One would expect different values from two different models, so the question is just a little unclear at the moment.

Comment: This is reminiscent of Malthusian economics: if one model asserts exponential growth and the other one, linear growth, then eventually the two models will predict wildly different futures based on the same data. That's because the assumptions they make about the world are different.  *There is no reconciliation;* there is only the possibility of rejecting either (or both) models as more is learned.

Comment: A Transfer Function model is a time series model that can include both the history of Y and contemporary and lagged effects of an X series.This model could be of the form Y(t) = Y(t-1)*0.4 + 2*X(t) + 1.2.